Como leer un archivo csv separado por comas y guardar los datos en una lista en C
Tengo un problema bastante raro con un código el cual carga caracteres de un archivo CSV a una lista circular en c. El problema viene tanto del lado de los caracteres leídos como de la lista, por parte de los caracteres leídos pasa lo siguiente:
Al leer el primero de los datos en el archivo csv y guardarlo en una variable de tipo char[2] lo hace bien
strcpy(n,strtok(line,","));
printf("n=%s\n",n); //en consola: n=nm

El problema viene al leer el segundo dato
strcpy(c,strtok(NULL,","));
printf("n=%s\n",n); //en consola: n=
printf("c=%s\n",c); //en consola: c=c

No se porque pero parece que borra el dato leido anteriormente y asi sucesivamente con todos los datos leídos.
Ahora bien, viendolo asi uno pensaria que al mostrar la lista mostrará solo el ultimo dato de todas las lineas del CSV, pero no; por alguna extraña razon la lista almacena 7 nodos/líneas nomas de las 38 que hay y ni siquiera son las primeras:
Líneas guardadas en negritas (por supuesto solo el ultimo dato de la línea):
nm,c,l,g,m,i
00,v,4,0,0,0
27,r,1,3,1,1
10,n,3,1,0,0
25,r,3,3,1,1
**29,n,2,3,1,1**
**12,r,1,1,0,0**
**08,n,2,1,0,0**
**19,r,3,2,1,1**
**31,n,3,3,1,1**
**18,r,1,2,0,0**
**06,n,1,1,0,0**
21,r,1,2,1,1
...

Dejo el codigo a continuacion junto al contenido del archivo CSV, si alguien me puede ayudar estaria muy agradecido de verdad. Saludos.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void error(){
    printf("ERROR");
}

typedef struct casilla{
    char num[2];
    char color;
    char linea;
    char grupo;
    bool mayor;
    bool impar;
    struct casilla *sig;
}casilla;

casilla *posicion=NULL;
casilla *ultimacarga=NULL;

void cargarruleta(){
    int i=0;
    char may[1],impa[1],line[13],n[2],c[1],l[1],g[1];
    FILE *file;
    file=fopen("maparuleta.csv","r");
    if(file==NULL){
        error();
    }
    while(i<39){
        casilla *nueva=(casilla*)malloc(sizeof(casilla));
        fscanf(file,"%s",line);
        //printf("%s\n",line);
        strcpy(n,strtok(line,","));
        printf("n=%s\n",n);
        strcpy(c,strtok(NULL,","));
        printf("n=%s\n",n);
        printf("c=%s\n",c);
        strcpy(l,strtok(NULL,","));
        printf("n=%s\n",n);
        printf("c=%s\n",c);
        strcpy(g,strtok(NULL,","));
        strcpy(may,strtok(NULL,","));
        strcpy(impa,strtok(NULL,","));
        nueva->num[0]=n[0];
        nueva->num[1]=n[1];
        nueva->color=c[0];
        nueva->linea=l[0];
        nueva->grupo=g[0];
        if(may[0]=='1'){
            nueva->mayor=true;
        } else{
            nueva->mayor=false;
        }
        if(impa[0]=='1'){
            nueva->impar=true;
        } else{
            nueva->impar=false;
        }
        if(i>0){
            if(posicion==NULL){
                posicion=nueva;
                posicion->sig=posicion;
                ultimacarga=posicion;
            } else{
                ultimacarga->sig=nueva;
                nueva->sig=posicion;
                ultimacarga=nueva;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
}
    
void mostrarruleta(){
    casilla *recorrer=posicion;
    do{
        printf("%s - %c - %c - %c \n",recorrer->num,recorrer->color,recorrer->linea,recorrer->grupo);
        recorrer=recorrer->sig;
    } while(recorrer!=posicion);
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    cargarruleta();
    mostrarruleta();
    return 0;
}

Contenido del archivo CSV (nombre: maparuleta.csv):
nm,c,l,g,m,i
00,v,4,0,0,0
27,r,1,3,1,1
10,n,3,1,0,0
25,r,3,3,1,1
29,n,2,3,1,1
12,r,1,1,0,0
08,n,2,1,0,0
19,r,3,2,1,1
31,n,3,3,1,1
18,r,1,2,0,0
06,n,1,1,0,0
21,r,1,2,1,1
33,n,1,3,1,1
16,r,3,2,0,0
04,n,3,1,0,0
23,r,2,2,1,1
35,n,2,3,1,1
14,r,2,2,0,0
02,n,2,1,0,0
00,v,0,4,0,0
28,n,3,3,1,0
09,r,1,1,0,1
26,n,2,3,1,0
30,r,1,3,1,0
11,n,2,1,0,1
07,r,3,1,0,1
20,n,2,2,1,0
32,r,2,3,1,0
17,n,2,2,0,1
05,r,2,1,0,1
22,n,3,2,1,0
34,r,3,3,1,0
15,n,1,2,0,1
03,r,1,1,0,1
24,n,1,2,1,0
36,r,1,3,1,0
13,n,3,2,0,1
01,r,3,1,0,1


Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour] para leer sobre el funcionamiento del sitio y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. Un saludo.

Hay varios problemas en tu código.
Cadenas de caracteres y \0
Primero, tienes definidas una serie de variables como arreglos de caracteres, sin espacio para el caracter de terminación (NULL o \0). Esto está bien, es bastante común manejarlo así, pero debes recordarlo a medida que escribes tu programa.
Esto es importante pues, luego, llamas a funciones como strcpy o printf con el modificador %s que operan sobre cadenas de caracteres terminados en NULL y que, por tanto, lo tendrán en cuenta dentro de su lógica.
Analicemos que pasa con esta línea cuando se está procesando la primera línea del archivo.
strcpy(n,strtok(line,","));

La llamada a strtok(line,",") sobre la primera línea del archivo va a devolver una cadena de 3 caracteres, "00\n".
Luego strcpy va a copiar esos 3 caracteres a la variable n, que es el destino en la llamada. Pero n está declarada así:
char n[2]

Esto provocará un desbordamiento en la memoria y el caracter NULL va a ser copiado a un espacio de memoria que ya no pertenece a la variable n sino potencialmente a otra que resulte estar a la par en el espacio de memoria o, con suerte, a una dirección de memoria que no está asignada a tu programa, lo que causará un segmentation fault.
Dado que el valor se logra copiar sin producir este error, la llamada a printf("n=%s\n",n); parece funcionar bien, pues se imprime el valor esperado, sin embargo aquí también está ocurriendo un desbordamiento de memoria y se está leyendo más allá de la memoria realmente asignada a n.
Es justamente por esta razón que, cuando se ejecuta la siguiente línea de código:
printf("c=%s\n",c); 

ahora la variable c toma un valor y, como por arte de magia, la variable n lo pierde. Lo que está ocurriendo es que ocurre también un desbordamiento de memoria y el compilador está asignando memoria para la variable n justo después de la variable c, por lo que el caracter NULL se escribe en n[0] y, por eso, ahora se imprime una cadena vacía al imprimir n.
Puedes ahorrarte todo esto si trabajas con punteros a cadenas terminadas en NULL, por ejemplo:
    char *may, *impa, *n, *c, *l, *g;
    //bla, bla, bla
    n = strtok(line, delim);
    c = strtok(NULL, delim);
    l = strtok(NULL, delim);
    g = strtok(NULL, delim);
    may = strtok(NULL, delim);
    impa = strtok(NULL, delim);
    
    printf("n=%s\n",n);
    printf("c=%s\n",c);
    printf("l=%s\n",l);
    printf("g=%s\n",g);
    printf("may=%s\n",may);
    printf("impa=%s\n",impa);
    nueva->num[0]=n[0];
    nueva->num[1]=n[1];
    nueva->color=c[0];
    nueva->linea=l[0];

Otra posible solución es que dejes espacio para los caracteres NULL en la declaración de variables:
    char may[2],impa[2],line[13],n[3],c[2],l[2],g[2];

De esta manera, la copia ocurrirá sin desbordamiento de memoria y todo funcionará como esperas.
Para finalizar con este segmento, debes tener en cuenta, si usas cadenas no terminadas en NULL, que la llamada a printf con el modificador %s, sin indicar una longitud, puede también desbordarse en la memoria y va a imprimir todos los caracteres contiguos que encuentre hasta el NULL o producir un SEG FAULT.
Para no cambiar tu estructura, por ejemplo, puedes agregar un modificador de longitud al imprimir el campo num:
printf("%.2s - %c - %c - %c \n",recorrer->num,recorrer->color,recorrer->linea,recorrer->grupo);

El %.2s asegura que solamente se imprimiran 2 caracteres, sin buscar el NULL, por lo que no se leerá más allá en la memoria.
Manejo de la Lista
Primero, llama las variables de manera más adecuada, según su uso. Por ejemplo, primero y ultimo, o inicio y fin
Llamándoles de la primera forma sugerida, para ir agregando elementos a la lista, sugiero usar algo como:
    if (primero == NULL) {
        primero = nuevo;
    } else {
        ultimo->sig = nuevo;
    }
    ultimo = nuevo;
    i++;

Que es más fácil de escribir, leer y mantener.
También hay un error en el recorrido de la lista, pues obvias el último elemento. Dado que primero imprimes y luego asignas el elementos siguiente, debes recorrer hasta que la variable de recorrido sea NULL y no hasta que sea el último elemento, si no este ya no se imprime.
Otras recomendaciones

Al leer un archivo, lo habitual no es leer un número fijo de líneas, sino leer el archivo hasta que termine.
Esto lo haces comparando el resultado de fscanf con el marcador de fin de archivo (EOF), por ejemplo:
  while (EOF != fscanf(file,"%s",line)) {


Si las columnas de tu archivo siempre van a ser de ancho fijo, puedes simplificar el código trasladando la información directamente de la variable line a la nueva casilla usando strncpy, que recibe la longitud de caracteres a copiar como parámetro.


Poniendo todo junto, quedaría algo como:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void error(){
    printf("ERROR");
}

typedef struct casilla{
    char num[2];
    char color;
    char linea;
    char grupo;
    bool mayor;
    bool impar;
    struct casilla *sig;
}casilla;

casilla *primero=NULL;
casilla *ultimo=NULL;

bool cargarruleta(){
    char line[13];
    char *may, *impa, *n, *c, *l, *g;
    FILE *file;
    file=fopen("maparuleta.csv","r");
    if(file==NULL){
        error();
        return(false);
    }
    const char delim[2] = ",";
    
    while(EOF != fscanf(file,"%s",line)){
        casilla *nuevo=(casilla*)malloc(sizeof(casilla));
        n = strtok(line, delim);
        c = strtok(NULL, delim);
        l = strtok(NULL, delim);
        g = strtok(NULL, delim);
        may = strtok(NULL, delim);
        impa = strtok(NULL, delim);
        nuevo->num[0]=n[0];
        nuevo->num[1]=n[1];
        nuevo->color=c[0];
        nuevo->linea=l[0];
        nuevo->grupo=g[0];
        if(may[0]=='1'){
            nuevo->mayor=true;
        } else{
            nuevo->mayor=false;
        }
        if(impa[0]=='1'){
            nuevo->impar=true;
        } else{
            nuevo->impar=false;
        }
        
        if (primero == NULL) {
            primero = nuevo;
        } else {
            ultimo->sig = nuevo;
        }
        ultimo = nuevo;
    }
    return(true);
}
    
void mostrarruleta(){
    casilla *recorrer=primero;
    do{
        printf("%.2s - %c - %c - %c \n",recorrer->num,recorrer->color,recorrer->linea,recorrer->grupo);
        recorrer=recorrer->sig;
    } while(recorrer!=NULL);
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (cargarruleta()) {
      mostrarruleta();
    }
    return 0;
}

OJO: No tengo un compilador a mano, es probable que el código publicado tenga errores, en ese caso, intenta resolverlo y si no puedes, deja un comentario con el error del compilador o el error en tiempo de ejecución para revisar.
